# Unable to read CSV file in a nested loop

Tags: python, file, loops, csv

```
  import csv
s = open('models.csv')
checkIt = csv.reader(s)
o = open('data.csv')
csv_o = csv.reader(o)
for c in checkIt:   
    abc = c[0].split(".")
    abcd = abc[2]
    commodity_type = abcd[6:]
    print(commodity_type)
    **for csv in csv_o:
        print(csv)
        print(commodity_type)**
```

print function is executing only one time, it should execute for 4 time because i have 4 rows in models.csv file.

please give some solution that nested for loop run for according to number of row in models.csv

Comment: why don't you reverse the loop, put the contents of `models.csv` in memory, and then loop once over `data.csv`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try resetting the file pointer that `csv_o` points to.

```
for csv in csv_o:
    print(csv)
    print(commodity_type)

o.seek(0)
```

That should automatically make the CSV reader begin reading from the start of the file from the next iteration onwards.